# Export function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, function, components, svelte

I am trying to display the content of the selected li tag based on its content.
Eg: if user click color, the content should display all the colors.
Otherwise, shapes will display all shapes.

The above is just an example but what I want to achieve is something similar. I have 2 svelte components.
SchemaNav.svelte basically handles the Tab function between different li items. And Table.svelte handles the tables that I want the content to be displayed.

SchemaNav.svelte

```
<script>
var list;
    export function onItemClick(names) {
         list = names.table_name; //to get the selected li value 
        return list;
    }

     
<script>
    {#if activeItem === "common"}
        <div class="content">
            <div class="tname">
                {#each name as names }
                    {#if names.table_schema === activeItem}
                        <ul>
                            <li on:click={() => onItemClick(names)}>
                            {names.table_name}</li>
                            
                        
                            
                        </ul>
                    {/if}
                {/each}
            </div>
            <Table  />
            
    </div>  
{/if}
```

Tables.svelte

```
<script>
import {onItemClick} from './SchemaNav.svelte';
</script>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">
                <caption class="text-center">Column names</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column Name</th>
                            <th>Data Type</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {#if {onItemClick} === info.table_name}
                    {#each info as item}
                        
                        <tr>
                            <td>{item.column_name}</td>
                            <td>{item.data_type}</td>
                        </tr>
                     
                    {/each}
                    {/if}
                    </tbody>
            </table>
```

The error I'm getting is:GET http://localhost:3000/client/undefined net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ catalog:70

How do I get the selected Li item to display its content accordingly...

Comment: Please consider adding a minimal reproductible example using [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svelte-svelte) for example. I downvoted your question since it's the second time that you provide really poor infos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not exactly sure what you want to do. I think you should make a very simple example with REPL, then you would get better answers.

Maybe one solution would be:

Give the table-component the `list` as a prop `<Table {list} />` and in the table-component `export let list`. Now you have a reference to selected `list` in the table-comp.

Here is a REPL:
https://svelte.dev/repl/6c756e5f65784b1796dd92dd148c04da?version=3.24.1

You can also give the table a filtered list, which includes all the info you need to show and then you won’t need to do any processing in the table-comp, only show the data.

Here is a REPL for a second solution:
https://svelte.dev/repl/5668cdee007c4418b13667350a589f80?version=3.24.1

Comment: Hi there! Yes, I was trying to do something like that. Your answer helped me! Thank u